# Daterangepicker is broken on tabindex

Tags: jquery, html, daterangepicker

I'm using [daterangpicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com)

Here is my html

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" tabindex="1" id="myText">
<input type="text" class="form-control calendar-overview-left" tabindex="2" id="myCalendar">
```

I have initialized daterangepicker

```
$(function() {
$('#myCalendar').daterangepicker();});
```

This working fine on input click. But when I'm tabbing to the calendar input, daterangpicker is broken like [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFzvp.png).

Can you help me to solve the problem?

Comment: @forQuestion03 where is daterange  input used

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've updated the code, please see it.

Comment: @ForQuestion03 update you complete html code

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range check this